# Division between samples in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, division

It is possible to do a division in a sql query?

I'll give you an example:

I have:

Table_1 with "n" samples, and I can add rows so this number could change day by day.

and

Table_2 in which I do a count on my selected samples

Can I do:

#Samples_table_1 / #Samples_table_2 ?

```
(SELECT COUNT(X)
FROM TABLE_1
WHERE CONDITION;)
/
(SELECT COUNT(Y)
FROM TABLE_2
WHERE CONDITION;)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose your above query (`after removing the semicolon`) by another `SELECT`.

```
SELECT 
IFNULL((
    SELECT 
    COUNT(X)
    FROM TABLE_1
    WHERE CONDITION
),0)
/
IFNULL((
    SELECT 
    COUNT(Y)
    FROM TABLE_2
    WHERE CONDITION
 ),1);
```

In addition to Gordon's answer:

If you expect fractional answer then use `/` operator like above.

And if you expect `integer` as answer then use `DIV` like below:

```
SELECT 
    IFNULL((
        SELECT 
        COUNT(X)
        FROM TABLE_1
        WHERE CONDITION
    ),0)
    DIV
    IFNULL((
        SELECT 
        COUNT(Y)
        FROM TABLE_2
        WHERE CONDITION
     ),1);
```

Comment: That's perfect for my cause! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can just put a `select` in front:

```
SELECT ((SELECT COUNT(X) FROM TABLE_1 WHERE CONDITION) /
        (SELECT COUNT(Y) FROM TABLE_2 WHERE CONDITION)
       )
```

You also need to remove the semicolons.

If you are concerned about divide by zero, I would move the expressions to the `from` and phrase it as:

```
SELECT (x.cnt / NULLIF(y.cnt, 0))
FROM (SELECT COUNT(X) as cnt FROM TABLE_1 WHERE CONDITION) x CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(Y) as cnt FROM TABLE_2 WHERE CONDITION) as y
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, Isn't the `null` checking supposed to be like this: `SELECT (NULLIF(x.cnt,0) / NULLIF(y.cnt, 1))` ? correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @1000111 . . . You are incorrect.  The goal is to get a `NULL` value out of the expression if the denominator is 0 -- to avoid a divide by zero error.

Comment: Sorry, I never used `NULLIF` before. Just thought `IFNULL = NULLIF`. Thanks Gordon.